# Adding Security Message to RHEL 5 Login Screen

Tags: linux

What are the steps to configure the login screen of Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 to display a large paragraph of text?

Background Information: The text is a security warning required by the company I work for to be presented to all users prior to them logging in. They must be able to read the text prior to logging in.

We are using GDM and it does not read /etc/issue by default. I have placed a copy of the text under the [greeter] section in /etc/gdm/custom.conf. The issue is that the text is displayed on one line and runs off the screen.

Is there a way to present the whole paragraph in plain text without having to resort to using a rendered background image of the text such as how this DOE employee did?

Example of using image: http://cc.jlab.org/docs/security/banners/linux-graphical-banner.html

Answer (score 1):

Place the text in a file, and point InfoMsgFile to the file.

```
[greater]
InfoMsgFile=/etc/motd
```

Comment: That did not work.  Only the first line of the banner is displayed on the screen.  The rest of the text runs off the screen.

Comment: I see, the messagebox doesn't wordwrap. You have to put your own linebreaks in the message. I use this myself for RHEL5 on some machines.

Comment: I have linebreaks in the message.  Which gdm login theme are you using on RHEL5?